# Using Sos (dumpheap etc) from test code?

Tags: .net, memory, garbage-collection, memory-leaks

I've recently tracked down a memory leak in my application and I'd like to add a test case to check that it stays that way.  What I want to do is this:

```
 int numberOfInstancesBeforeFunction = GetNumberOfInstancesInMemory(typeof(MyClass));

 PerformFunction();

 GC.Collect();

 int numberOfInstancesAfterFunction = GetNumberOfInstancesInMemory(typeof(MyClass));

 Assert.AreEqual(numberOfInstancesBeforeFunction, numberOfInstancesAfterFunction, "mem leak");
```

Is this possible?

Thanks,

Euan

Comment: Did you ever find a way to actually control sos from code? I'd like to be able to do more than just reference counting...

Answer (score 0):

There is advice on how to achieve this using [WeakReference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.weakreference.aspx) in the accepted answer from @Adam Robinson [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1168746/c-count-number-of-objects-of-class-type-within-class-method).

`GetNumberOfInstancesInMemory` would have to check a static container of `MyClass` object `WeakReference`s to see how many return `thisReference.IsAlive = true;` (and remove any that have `isAlive = false`.

Any construction of `MyClass` would add a reference to itself to the static container.

I would think there's an elegant Linq way to encapsulate the required logic.

I don't know if there is any way to do this without incorporating extra code into your `MyClass`.

Comment: @Euan - great, but take note of @Hans Passant's caveat re introducing new leaks along the way.  Classic Heisenbug opportunity.