# Count number of instances created of struct

Tags: c#, struct

I am looking for a way to determine the number of struct objects that are created in my program. It is for educational purposes.

I found this answer on SO, which works for classes: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12276687/363224. So I tried to do something similar with a `struct`, but as expected it doesn't work like that.

```
public struct Car
{
    public string brand;

    public static int ObjectsConstructed { get; private set; }

    public Car(string brand)
    {
        this.brand = brand;
        ObjectsConstructed++;
    }
}

...

Car car1 = new Car("VW");
Car car2 = car1; // How can we increment the ObjectsConstructed?
List<Car> carList = new List<Car>();
carList.Add(car1); // How can we increment the ObjectsConstructed?
```

The `Car(string)` constructor is not called, because the copy of the struct object is called some kind of memcpy and doesn't go through the constructor. A struct also doesn't allow explicit parameterless constructors.

How does one make sort of a copy constructor that can be handled? Or is there another way to get this information out of the runtime via reflection?

---

EDIT

I wrote a test that shows what I mean:

```
// This test passes, firstCar and sameCar are not the same.
[TestMethod]
public void HowManyTimesIsACarCreated()
{
    Car firstCar = new Car();
    Car sameCar = firstCar;
    sameCar.brand = "Opel";

    // It seems that you can change sameCar without changing firstCar
    Assert.AreNotEqual(firstCar.brand, sameCar.brand);

    // This one is tricky, because firstCar and sameCar are passed as parameters, so new objects would again be created as I would see it.
    Assert.IsFalse(ReferenceEquals(firstCar, sameCar));
}
```

firstCar and sameCar do not point to the same object, since I can change the brand if sameCar, but firstCar is still the same.

Comment: This could only be done by the runtime, and even then not by passively inspecting things but by active tracking. Consider `new Car[100]` -- this just allocates a block of struct-sized memory to be carved up as an array. It technically also creates 100 instances, but this isn't counted as such anywhere. Meanwhile, calling a method that takes such a struct implicitly "creates" a copy, so add one more. Maintaining this count accurately and in real time per type would add so much overhead that it's not worth doing -- this is more in the realm of memory profilers.

Comment: @Rahul I changed the example to a `List.Add()`.

Comment: var car1 = new Car("");
var car2 = new Car("");
Console.WriteLine(Car.ObjectsConstructed); then definitely you will get count as 2

Comment: @ManuMohanT That is not the example I am looking for. I am looking for indirect copies that are made because of parameter passing or adding objects to lists. I have changed the example.

Comment: `carList.Add(car1);` also does not create new instance.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya What?! Then, how does this work with structs? Can someone point me to a good reference that explains me how it works with value types?

Comment: in such case you can just get the number of items in list using the `Count()` property of `List<T>`

Comment: @Marnix indirect copy?? there is no two objects in either of your examples. Reference doesnt mean that holds a fresh object. you already have the exact count of objects created

Comment: @Rahul Actually, `car2` was a different thing to `car1`, `struct` is a value type so an assignment like this would be a "new" object.

Comment: I did some more tests with a unit test. `car1` and `car2` are definitely not the same.

Comment: @DavidG Ahh!! that's a big mistake. didn't see that it's a `struct`.

Comment: @Marnix The short answer is that you can't track them, in the same way you can't track `int` or `double`. `struct`s have an implicit parameterless constructor so even if you define your own, there's nothing preventing code calling the parameterless version.

Comment: Basically, you can't do this. The compiler could even create copy operations behind the scenes which aren't always obvious. But it's rarely useful to know this anyway, in my experience - it would usually be a matter of avoiding copying for performance reasons, at which point you want decent benchmarking rather than a "number of copies made".

Comment: @JonSkeet I wanted to create an example for my students to show that it is indeed different for classes and structs and that you might not always want to use a struct. If it's even more than what you would theoretically expect, I'm still happy with any number that's bigger than 1.

Comment: @DavidG I tried to make a parameterless constructor, but it's prohibited in structs.

Comment: @Marnix No, I mean you cannot create one because it already exists.

Comment: I'm afraid there just isn't any way of doing this. I'd also try to avoid referring to "struct objects" - they're not objects in the normal sense. They're values.

Comment: Perhaps your students aren't ready to understand the deep underlying reasons and should just accept your best practice rules?